# How to add Nexus repository index in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We managed our maven repository using Sonatype Nexus, and in the ~.m2\setting.xml, set

```
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

to our Nexus repository.

In IntelliJ IDEA "Settings-->Maven-->Repositories-->Indexed Maven repositories", there are one local repository and one remote central repository "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2". However, there seems to be no way to index Nexus repository.

Without the index, I can't use the "Maven Artifact Search" inside IntelliJ IDEA, instead I have to search it in Nexus website, and then copy the dependency to the pom.xml, which is not quite convenient.

Can anybody tell me how to add Nexus repository index in IntelliJ IDEA, so that I can search artifacts inside IDEA?

below is my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>My repository</name>
      <url>http://1.2.3.4:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>My repository</name>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Check if you are using your local Maven installation or the built-in from IntelliJ. Do so by checking under *Maven* in your settings.

Comment: I used local Maven installation.

Comment: Then this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676796/adding-maven-repo-in-intellij - Make sure you update your Maven indices. You can do so in your Maven panel on the right.

Comment: I edited the question and added my settings.xml. With this setting, the "Indexed Maven Repositories" would be a local repository and remote "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2", not Nexus url. What's worse, it says "Error" if I try to update remote repository index.

Answer (score 2):

AFA I know this isn't possible, using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1. The only Maven repositories that are supported are local or *public* ones, per the docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven-repositories.html

@CrazyCoder, correct me if I'm wrong...

Related: [Adding maven repo in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676796/adding-maven-repo-in-intellij)

Comment: Nexus offers a "public" link to the repo, eg: http://myserver/content/groups/public It doesn't seem to require authentication. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: @ndtreviv that didn't work for me, but IntelliJ has made improvements to how maven repos are handled in the latest version, so maybe this works now?

Comment: the link to intellij's documentation about repositories doesn't mention that the only maven repositories that are supported are local or public. How do you know that?

Comment: I have my own group http://213.168.188.110:50001/nexus/content/groups/public/ and IntelliJ shows this under "Artifactory or Nexus service url" window, but the artefacts which are available cannot be found via IntelliJ. The group is not in published state as some of proxy repos in the group are not. When I add specific artefact into pom.xml it is downloaded, but the index doesn't work as I cannot search for artefact (nothing found.), so this still doesn't work. I am on 2016.3.4